# Access Vagrant VM via virtual host over LAN

Tags: apache, networking, vagrant

I have a web server running inside vagrant virtual machine on my host machine (A). I want another machine (B) to be able to view a website over the LAN.

[image]

In my vagrant config I have the following relevant lines of config:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

In my windows hosts file on host machine (A) I have:

```
192.168.33.10 awesomewebsite.dev
```

In the hosts file of the LAN machine (b) I have it pointed towards the IP of machine A

```
172.123.12.12 awesomewebsite.dev
```

I have an apache vhost file inside the VM with the following config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName awesomewebsite.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/awesomesite
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/awesome.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/awesome.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit awesomewebsite.dev on host machine, it works. But when I visit on machine B it doesn't appear to reach machine A. When I visit awesomesite.dev:8080 on machine B it ends up in the wrong web directory and gets permission errors.

I have added the following (just for testing, i know its not high security)

```
<Directory "/var/www">
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I need machine B to access the VM on machine A via the exact virtual host without the port. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

with a public network it should just work with the following

```
192.168.33.10 awesomewebsite.dev
```

on the Machine B. This machine should be able to see any VMs running on host A and treat it as a separate machine (it is registered on the network with its own network interface)

You then do not work to do any forwarding port when working with static IP as you can just access any port directly from the IP